# How can I use grave accents or backticks (`) in a question?

Tags: support, markdown, formatting

Is there any way to type two back-tick (or grave accent) characters (`) in my question without formatting my text in unwanted way?

I know I can enter a grave accent at one place, like this:  <kbd>Alt+`</kbd>. 
But as soon as I try to repeat this character anywhere in this text block, the whole formatting of the sentence goes wrong.
One work around is to type single quote (') in place of back-tick, but what if we DO want to show the back-tick (grave accent).

Comment: @vssher That formats the text as code, which is not what the OP is asking.

Comment: Hi, and welcome to Meta! Your question was hard to understand, and you used the wrong name for the ` character (it's called backtick or backquote, not tile - tilde is the character ~), so I took the liberty of editing it. Feel free to re-edit if something's wrong.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

#### How can I type two backtick characters without formatting my text in unwanted way?

Use `\` as an escape character:

This is some text with `backticks` and some more `text with backticks`

Source:

```
This is some text with \`backticks\` and some more \`text with backticks\`
```

> **Backslash Escapes**
>
> Markdown allows you to use backslash escapes to generate literal
>   characters which would otherwise have special meaning in Markdown’s
>   formatting syntax. For example, if you wanted to surround a word with
>   literal asterisks (instead of an HTML `<em>` tag), you can use
>   backslashes before the asterisks, like this:
>
> ```
> \*literal asterisks\*
> ```
>
> Markdown provides backslash escapes for the following characters:
>
> ```
> \   backslash
> `   backtick
> *   asterisk
> _   underscore
> {}  curly braces
> []  square brackets
> ()  parentheses
> #   hash mark
> +   plus sign
> -   minus sign (hyphen)
> .   dot
> !   exclamation mark
> ```

Source [Daring Fireball: Markdown Syntax Documentation](https://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/syntax#backslash)

Comment: Thanks, that's exactly what I needed.

Answer (score 8):

This question is rather confused. What does the Alt key have to do with your requiring two backticks ` [not tildes, btw, they're ~ ]

Stack Exchange uses markdown for formatting, which means two backticks surround a `code block like this`. This is entered as

`a code block like this`

If you want to enter any markdown & not show as such, then you can escape formatting marks using backslash \

So if you want `two backticks without formatting` you type

```
\`two backticks without formatting\`
```

This & much more formatting help is available from within the text space, right above where you type your question or answer.

Comment: I wanted to include/write two `` (two back ticks/grave accents) in my question. And since I didn't know about the escape character and its use, I wasn't able to format my question, as I wanted. But now, after the answer, I do. Thanks.

Comment: `Alt+`` key (alt plus back-tick) was just an example/term which I needed to type in another website. For which this question arose.